# jQuery this inside each loop

Tags: jquery

Inside the `initialize()` function there is a jQuery `each` loop. Inside that loop is a reference to `this.dbcolumns` which is obviously not working as jQuery has reassigned `this` to the current loop element. So how can I reference `this.dbcolumns` from inside the loop? It works outside the loop ok.

```
function datatable() {
    this.url = '';
    this.htmltable = '';
    this.dbtable = '';
    this.dbcolumns = new Array();
    this.idfield = 'id';
    this.pageno = 0;
    this.pagesize = 15;
    this.totalpages = 0;
    this.totalrecords = 0;
    this.searchterm = '';

    this.initialize = function() {
        this.dbtable = $(this.htmltable).attr('data-table');
        this.dbcolumns.push(this.idfield);
        $(this.htmltable + ' th[data-field]').each(function(i, col){
            this.dbcolumns.push( $(col).attr('data-field') ); /* <<<<<<<<<< this line */
        });
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: `var that =this` then use `that`...

Comment: Side note: function expressions should have a trailing semicolon.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

make a reference to the "this" that you want to hold onto outside of the loop.

```
var self = this;
```

then you can use "self" inside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Store a reference to `this` outside the `each` callback, or use the ES5 [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
$(this.htmltable + ' th[data-field]').each(function(i, col){
     this.dbcolumns.push( $(col).attr('data-field') );
}.bind(this));
```

Or, as noted in the comments use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
$(this.htmltable + ' th[data-field]').each($.proxy(function(i, col){
     this.dbcolumns.push( $(col).attr('data-field') );
}, this));
```

Comment: With jQuery it may be advisable to use `$.proxy` because `.bind` is not supported everywhere.

Comment: True. I've been working a lot with PrototypeJS recently (which shims `bind` for you), so I keep mixing up jQuery patterns and Prototype patterns.

Answer (score 3):

The common JS pattern to solve is to use closure:

```
this.initialize = function() {
    var that = this;

    this.dbtable = $(this.htmltable).attr('data-table');
    this.dbcolumns.push(this.idfield);
    $(this.htmltable + ' th[data-field]').each(function(i, col){
        that.dbcolumns.push( $(col).attr('data-field') ); /* <<<<<<<<<< this line */
    });
    return this;
}
```