# how to access this with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm newbie to jQuery.so please tell me how to use `this` variable inside the loop.

For eg.

```
this.tblsize=10;
$.each([1,2],function(idx,val){
console.log(this.tblsize)
});
```

Output

```
undefined
undifined
```

But I need to get output as `10 10`.

Anything wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery this inside each loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070462/jquery-this-inside-each-loop)

Answer (score 2):

You need to utilize [closure](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) in order to access `this` from a different scope:

```
this.tblsize=10;
var self = this;
$.each([1,2],function(idx,val){
    console.log(self.tblsize)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just dont use this, use any other variable name:

```
var tblsize=10;
$.each([1,2],function(idx,val){
console.log(tblsize)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this `inside` the anonymous function since it's another scope.

This should work

```
    this.tblsize=10;
    var thisref = this;

    $.each([1,2],function(idx,val){
    console.log(thisref.tblsize)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

***Just Try with the following example :***

```
<ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
</ul>

$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": "" + $(this).text() );
});
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of `this` before calling the $.each. Within $.each `this` will refers to elements of `$.each()`.

```
this.tblsize=10;
var $this = this;
$.each([1,2],function(idx,val){
    console.log($this.tblsize)
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

Lets see you code:

```
this.tblsize = 10;
```

Here, the `tblsize` value has been specified outside the scope of `$.each()`

Next if you do:

```
$.each([1,2],function(idx,val){
      console.log(this)
});
```

You will get the values like `1` & `2`, since `this` here refers to the inner result scope of `$.each()` method. So, in your case, if you do something like `this.tblsize`, you would surely get something like `undefined` since there's no variable with this name inside each.

Hence, to get what you want you can simply create a circular global object, store the outside scope variable in it and access it inside the `$.each()` method, like:

```
this.tblsize = 10;

// circular global object
var table_size = this;

$.each([1,2],function(idx,val){
      console.log(table_size.tblsize);        // way 1
      console.log($(table_size)[0].tblsize);  // way 2
});
```